# How to add different css class dynamically in a loop every 3 times

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, loops, foreach

Basically what i need to do is looping all the posts and add css to article class like "cb-no-1" and the second one "cb-no-2" and the third one "cb-no-3" and repait it again until there's no post.

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
    {
        //First iteration 
        <article class= "cb-no-1">              
        </article>

         //Second iteration
         <article class= "cb-no-2">              
        </article>

        //Third iteration
         <article class= "cb-no-3">              
        </article>

       //Fourth iteration
         <article class= "cb-no-1">              
        </article>

      //and so on.
    }
```

How to achive it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable and increment that in the loop and use this variable name to build the class name.  When the variable reaches 3 (or your limit), reset it to initial value.

```
@{
   var counter = 0;
}

@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
  if (counter >= 3)
  {
    counter = 0;
  }
  <article class= "cb-no-@(++counter)">@post.Title</article>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a variable like as `i` inside the loop which is inited from 1 and increases in each loop and when it reachs the 4, reset it to 1

then use it for class name

Answer (score 0):

Shyju, the first responder, has the right idea, but there are two modifications you need to make to his answer.

First, his code gives you a variable from 0 to 2. you asked for 1 to 3,. so the initialization needs to be "var counter = 1" and the "if" test needs to be just greater than 3, not greater than or equal to 3. Or you could change the 3 to a 4, such as:  if (counter >= 4).

The second item left off of that code snippet is something to increment the counter.  I'm not sure which dialect or language you are writing in but something like:

Counter+=1
or
counter = counter + 1

Modified, that code snippet would look like:

```
   var counter = 1;
    @foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
    {
      if (counter >= 4)   
      { 
        counter = 0; 
      }
      <article class= "cb-no-@(++counter)">@post.Title</article>
      counter += 1 
     }
```

Again, I do not know which language you are writing in so check my syntax carefully.

Comment: Your statement is wrong ! the Op's objective is to generate the css class names from 1 to 3, which my code does. Also the statement `++counter` increment the variable value and use it. [Read about pre-icrementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) . Your code increments it twice in the loop (one with `++counter` and one with `counter+=1`. If you do not believe me, just copy and paste the code from my answer and try it. Oh wait, i have done it for you. Enjoy https://dotnetfiddle.net/7YYg4w